# What are the supported IDE's for snowflake cloud database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am curious to know what are the supported IDEs for Snowflake database. I tried using SQL Developer and Aginity but doesn't seem to work. I am not asking for the top 10 IDEs, but commonly used tools.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any ODBC/JDBC compatible tools should work, but you need to configure it properly, seeting up the proper driver and extra Snowflake-specific fields (e.g. `account`)

My favorite (except for Snowflake's Web UI) recently is [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) - it doesn't (yet) support the exact Snowflake syntax, but connectivity works great, and managing multiple sessions, tabs is first class.

You can see [documentation](https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/How-to-Configure-Snowflake-connections-for-Datagrip) on how to use it with Snowflake, it also has examples for other tools, e.g. [SQL Workbench/J](https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/configuring-sql-workbenchj-to-use-snowflake)

Comment: My biggest complaint about using DataGrip is that it still doesn't support the use of key based authentication. If using MFA, the only IDE that doesn't truly suck seems to be the web option offered by Snowflake.